# Ionic AngularJS build android on ubuntu

Tags: android, angularjs, linux, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I created mobile application with Ionic. I want build application and I've a problem, I try build application on Vagrant but I get response error.

> ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try
>   setting setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your
>   'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory

My .profile:

> export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools" export
>   ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
>   export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS"
>   ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux
>   ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
>   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/u$
>   ANDROID_SDK=/opt/android-sdk-linux

How fix?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may try this

> export ANDROID_HOME=/installation-location/android-sdk-linux
>
> export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Look to the [source](https://spring.io/guides/gs/android/) for more details